# pyodbc returning different set of drivers

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, pyodbc, conda

When I run the following set of lines, I get two different answers based on which conda env I'm currently working on.

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

The environment is a 2.7 32bit environment I'm using to automate some of my company's reporting whereas the root is a 2.7 64bit environment.
The list when I run it in the root environment is my regular list of ODBC drivers when I go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI but I have no idea how the environment list is populated from. It contains the following drivers at the bottom.

Ideally, I'd like to add the Access 2007 (*.accdb) driver to the environment's available drivers as well.

Thanks!

- conda-root drivers

  - Amazon Redshift (x64)

    - Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
    - Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
    - Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
    - MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver
    - MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
    - PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)
    - PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)
    - SQL Server
    - SQL Server Native Client 10.0
    - SQL Server Native Client 11.0
- py27_32 drivers

  - SQL Server Native Client 10.0

    - Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
    - Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
    - SQL Server Native Client 11.0
    - CR ODBC XML Driver 4.20
    - Driver para o Microsoft Visual FoxPro
    - Microsoft Visual FoxPro-Treiber
    - Microsoft dBase VFP Driver (*.dbf)
    - Microsoft FoxPro VFP Driver (*.dbf)
    - Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver
    - Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
    - Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
    - Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
    - Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
    - Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
    - Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
    - Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
    - Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
    - Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
    - Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
    - Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
    - Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
    - SQL Server
    - Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
    - Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)

Answer (score 1):

Solution Found:

Apparently Windows has separate set of ODBC drivers for 32bit and 64bit. 32bit drivers in a 64bit system can be found at

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI